# Upload image to S3 using AWS SDK.

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk

So I'm trying to upload an image up to S3 using the AWS-SDK. The upload is working but sometimes I run into a warning/ error and I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening.

If anyone has any ideas greatly appreciated.

Here's the source code:

```
      const s3 = new AWS.S3();
      const ext = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
      const type = `image/${ext}`;
      const filePath = `uploads/cache/${randomString({ length: 32 })}/${randomString(10)}.${ext}`;

      s3.putObject({
        Bucket: Config.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: filePath,
        ContentType: type,
        Body: new Buffer(data, 'base64'),
        ACL: 'public-read',
      }
```

Error or Warning

```
Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: C++ exception in 'nativeFlushQueueImmediate'

Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[58,58,58,58,58,58,15,27],[4,4,4,4,4,4,1,0],[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[136,100,1510545939677,false]],5224]
nativeFlushQueueImmediate@[native code]
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know it supported react-native. Is it the official sdk?

Comment: Yes, aws-sdk officially supports react native now. 
I'm using it on React native 0.49 and React 0.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually nothing wrong with the code. Sorry, it was a problem being caused with my async calls.

But at least its good to know uploading to S3 with aws-sdk is working nicely :D